# List of fields and whether or not they are Encrypted And tracked in Field history

Tags: apex, soql, encryption, describesobject

I have been wracking my brain trying to figure out a way to get a list of fields and include whether they are encrypted, and whether they are marked for field history tracking.  I seem to be able to get the encrypted list via apex execution using the getdescribe method, and I can get the field history tracking list in SOQL usig the entitydefinition and fielddefinition.  Does anyone have a way to output both?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though `encryptionScheme` only comes through the CustomField metadata, which means you would have to look at each field one at a time via the Tooling API query. If you did a metadata `retrieve()` (i.e. Package.xml), you would get the answer to both